# Change receive values in front

Tags: html, razor, razorengine

I have foreach loop with razor engine like this

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.Item3.Matriz.Select((value, i) => new { i, value })) {
<tr>
  <td>@item.value.Unidad</td>
  <td class="hidden">@Html.Hidden("Item3.Matriz[" + item.i + "].Unidad", item.value.Unidad, new { @id = "Unidad_" + item.i })</td>

</tr>
}
```

So in table I can receive into `Unidad` value only values `CORP`, `ALU` AND `PLA` I want to know if it´s possible to replace that values with anothers. 
For example:

If I receive `CORP` from backend change it in front for `CORPORATION`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the string function Replace() to replace the value of Unidad like what I have done in the modification of your code sample below.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Item3.Matriz.Select((value, i) => new { i, value })) {
    <tr>
      <td>@item.value.Unidad.ToString().Replace("CORP", "CORPORATION")</td>
      <td class="hidden">@Html.Hidden("Item3.Matriz[" + item.i + "].Unidad", item.value.Unidad, new { @id = "Unidad_" + item.i })</td>

    </tr>
    }
```

Comment: And its possible to annidate replaces?

Comment: yes, you can do .Replace("CORP", "CORPORATION").Replace("Some other value", "Your value").Replace....etc.